# Will a home page with minimum text hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, meta-description, homepage

I'm in the process of setting up a new website for my web and graphic design business.

I'm planning a home page that uses a very minimalist design: It will feature a large H1 title, a simple "Graphic and Web Design" sub title and a navigation menu. Aside from that it will all sit on a nice animated background. Aesthetically, it all looks nice enough. I will be setting up solid title, keyword and description meta tags - but im concerned that the lack of blocks of visible descriptive text will hurt my SEO.

Is this the case?

Comment: You say it is a "landing page" but that isn't an SEO concept.   Visitors from search land on pages about what they searched for.  A page without content isn't going to have anything to rank for.   You can create landing pages like this for advertisements, but not for SEO.

Comment: Thaks Stephen. Yes, you are right. I got my terms wrong. I was talking about the home page.

Comment: I assume the title of your home page will include your brand name?  If so, ranking for your brand name is the main job of the home page.   Little content isn't going to matter for that.

Comment: Yes, the title will be the brand name, with a <h2> sub-title containing a very short/concise description. eg "Graphic & Web Design". But as im starting to realise, it will be very difficult to get a simple page like this ranked reasonably well, when people actually search for "graphic and web design".

Comment: That is such a highly competitive term that you won't rank for it anyway.   You can have multiple pages and target different things.  For example you might have a "<your city> graphic and web design" page to attract local business.

Answer (score 4):

If your page will not be optimised well with appropriate text then it will not hurt in a bad way.

But it may be hard for you to get the desired ranking.

So, if you are serious about the ranking then i would say have a good website structure with appropriate content (Text, Images, videos etc).

Comment: Thanks. My sub pages will have plenty of content, so I understand that they will get picked up by the search engines. But I would like visitors to enter my website via the home page and navigate from there. But im not sure what can be done about it, as the pages with the bulk of content will rank higher than the home page no matter what I do, if im understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, a page with rich content will rank better than a simple page (Home page or other). Now, if you want your traffic to come via home page then you should consider having rich content there. Also, note that, if your inner pages might have more weight which will be useful to the customer then there is no point trying to get traffic on the home page and send to inner pages. All i can say is have a good website structure. And if your home page is generic then don't worry it should be fine and you can focus on inner pages.

Answer (score 2):

What is your home page for? If it exists for SEO, then you need a different approach. If it exists as a way to show off some work to people who came deliberately to check out your company, SEO may not be the most relevant item.

SEO =does= matter--but your home page doesn't necessarily have to be the page that comes up--that could be an "About" page or some other place where a text introduction to your company with appropriate terms appears.

Answer (score 1):

Most recommend using the home page as a way to orient your visitors. Welcome your visitors. Explain what the website is about. Point out how to get around (navigate the site). Have textual links to other pages on your site. Do what you can to provide what your target market is looking for. Try to keep them on your site without clicking away. First impressions are important!

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that a page should contain at least 300 words to be taken seriously.  The more the  merrier when it comes to content.